# django app file structure

Tags: django

Below is a common app file structure:

```
app/
    views.py
    forms.py
    urls.py
    tests.py
```

I found it's getting hard to maintain the code once the code base is getting big. I am thinking to organize the code based on individual web page, so each web page will have its own view.py, form.py and test.py.

```
app/
    views/
        page1_view.py
        page2_view.py

    forms/
        page1_form.py
        page2_form.py

    tests/
        page1_test.py
        page2_test.py
```

Is there any big issue I will run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Django understands packages and files.

Example if you use

```
app/
   views/
     page1_view.py
     page2_view.py
     __init__.py
```

you can reference the views as app.views.page1_views without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. In fact, I've often split views, tasks, and tests as you are doing.