# Error pushing Django project to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, python-2.7

I've been trying to fix this error for about an hour now and I've ran out of solutions so please help me.

> heroku create

runs fine no problems

> git push heroku master

```
    Counting objects: 119, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (118/118), done.
Writing objects: 100% (119/119), 1.39 MiB | 66 KiB/s, done.
Total 119 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Python app detected
-----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.3.
-----> Preparing Python runtime (python-2.7.3)
-----> Installing Distribute (0.6.34)
-----> Installing Pip (1.2.1)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.2.1)
       Downloading/unpacking Django==1.4.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package Django

       Downloading/unpacking dj-database-url==0.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
         Downloading dj-database-url-0.2.1.tar.gz
         Running setup.py egg_info for package dj-database-url

       Downloading/unpacking psycopg2==2.4.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2

           no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/src/_build'
       Downloading/unpacking virtualenv==1.8.4.post1 (from -r requirements.txt (line     4))
         Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv==1.8.4.post1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: )
       No distributions matching the version for virtualenv==1.8.4.post1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
       Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python app

 To git@heroku.com:[blocked].git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:[blocked].git'
```

requirements file:

```
 >Django==1.4.3
 >dj-database-url==0.2.1
 >psycopg2==2.4.6
 >virtualenv==1.8.4.post1
```

procfile

> web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload

Heroku Logs:

```
    The 'heroku' gem has been deprecated and replaced with the Heroku Toolbelt, download and install from https://toolbelt.heroku.com.

2013-01-24T01:22:06+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by [private email]@yahoo.com
2013-01-24T01:22:06+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by [private email]@yahoo.com
2013-01-24T01:22:42+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-01-24T01:23:38+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2013-01-24T01:43:26+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-01-24T01:43:51+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2013-01-24T02:27:36+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-01-24T02:28:08+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2013-01-24T02:32:08+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-01-24T02:32:32+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2013-01-24T02:43:32+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-01-24T02:43:59+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2013-01-24T02:46:23+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-01-24T02:46:52+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2013-01-24T02:49:48+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-01-24T02:50:26+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
```

Comment: Pip cannot find the requirement for `virtualenv==1.8.4.post1`. You either need to change that to `1.8.4` (the current version). Typically, however, `virtualenv` isn't put in the requirements at all - unless the functions of your app relies on it.

Comment: I took it out of the requirements and got the same error.

Comment: Please post the file structure of your project, including your root folder and where your `.git` repo folder is located.

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing this right but here it goes. Root: .git, hellodjango, venv, .gitignore, manage.py, Procfile.txt, requirements.txt.

Comment: Edit the original thread so that you can show the file and folder structure. Similar to this post (Just a random post with file structure for reference): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398460/django-app-file-structure

Comment: Actually, to make it a lot easier I'll just give you the github link: https://github.com/catvalentine/hellodjango

Comment: Your file structure looks good. Can you run `heroku logs` from your project root and edit your original post with the log results.

Comment: I was working with rails and I decided to try django to see which one I liked more. Could rails be interfering with django?

Comment: Added my answer. I'm assuming you did not `git add .` and `git commit` after removing the virtualenv from your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this running by:

1. cloning your git repo
2. removing the `virtualenv==1.8.4` from your `requirements.txt`
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -m "removing virtualenv requirement"`
5. `git push heroku master`

I'm assuming you did not `git add .` and `git commit` after removing the virtualenv from your requirements. Any changes you make to a `git` repo will not go in effect, for both `github` and `heroku`, until you `add` and then `commit` the changes locally, and finally `push` them to remote repository i.e. **Github** or **Heroku**.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me! Such a careless mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that it can't find `virtualenv==1.8.4.post1` and when I try that command locally, I get the same error. It doesn't look like that version exists at pypi. Try changing your requirements.txt to `virtualenv==1.8.4`?

Answer (score 0):

For the heroku deployment you do not need the **virtualenv==1.8.4.post1** in the requirement.txt file, please remove that and place the procfile and requirements in the root of git.